# Http Post on a Json file not working

Tags: angular, http

Im trying to make a simple post on a json file on Angular, I called the service but it does not return anything on console neither on the network, am I missing something?

this is the snippet from the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http'

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface Todo {
  text: string
}

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addTodo(todo): Observable<Todo> {
    const newTodo = {
      text: todo.text
    }
    return this.http.post<Todo>('./assets/data/todo.json', newTodo);
  }
```

When I click on a button it calls this addTodo function, however it does not return me anything.

And yes, there is a file called todo.json inside the assets folder. Is it possible to make a simple HTTP post on a json file?

Comment: The request will start when you suscribe to the Observebl. Did you?

Comment: no, that explains it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot post to a Json file in `assets` folder directly. A web browser only supports `GET` calls to the files. To make the `http.post` working, you will have to use a web server to host the files .

One such web server which you can use easily is `json server`. It is available as an `npm` package. Use the `json server` to host your files and then use the URL provided by the `json server` to `post` the data. Read the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) for more understanding.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm using this json server now, it really helped me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. In your code, you are not passing the options header with the post call.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface Todo {
    text: string
}

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
    headers: Headers;
    options: RequestOptions;
    constructor(private http: Http) { 
       this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
       this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    }

    addTodo(todo): Observable<Todo> {
        const newTodo = {
        text: todo.text
    }
    return this.http.post<Todo>('./assets/data/todo.json', newTodo,this.options);
  }
```